# Can i set different name from the value of a JcomboBox in netBeans

Tags: java, swing

First of all I'm sorry if I cannot formulate this question correctly but my problem is as follows. I have a JcomboBox used in a file search program. In the jcombobox you have to chose the type of the object and so I did something like this.

```
type = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

type.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".psd", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".doc", ".docx" }));
```

I made a JcomboList whith ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".psd", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".doc", ".docx"  but I didn't like the look of the JcomboBox.

My question is this, can I assign a different name to the elements of the Jcombobox, different from their value in NetBeans?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), then I'd have a look at [Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Comment: Using the renderer example from the tutorial will break the default functionality of the combo box since you will no longer be able to select items using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a custom Object in the combo box. This object will contain two properties:

1. a value for display in the combo box
2. a value used for processing in the application.

Then you need to renderer the Object. Two approaches

1. Override the toString() method of the custom object to display the appropriate value. Check out [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for a working example using this approach.
2. Create a custom renderer to display the appropriate value. Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/). This would be the preferred approach as long as you use the included rendering class. This provides a more complete solution than you will find in the Swing tutorial, since the tutorial example break default combo box functionality.

Comment: ehh.. minus one for suggesting override toString - doing so for application reasons is always wrong (as I know that you know and knew those years ago;)

Answer (score -1):

```
x.setEditable(true);
x.setValue(str);
x.setEditable(false); //If You Want
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.